# Regex - Excluding the separator character from .*

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewrite-module

I'm having a string consisting of multiple blocks of 4 substrings, separated by the `|` character. As example take:

> |255|UpdatePanel|updatePanel1|somecontent1234|

Most likely there will be multiple continous blocks of 4 strings

> |255|UpdatePanel|updatePanel1|somecontent1234|256|UpdatePanel|updatePanel2|someOtherContent|

Now I need a regular expression that matches each of these blocks

```
\|([1-9]+)\|(UpdatePanel)\|(updatePanel1|updatePanel2)\|(.*)\|
```

The problem is, this seems to be matching the whole example string of above, and not 2 matches of 4 substrings

Do I somehow have to exclude the separator (|) from the .* or is it something else?

Comment: Replace `.*` with `[^|]*`, and I believe the ``\`` before the `(.*` is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace the greedy dot matching with a negated character class:

```
\|([1-9]+)\|(UpdatePanel)\|(updatePanel1|updatePanel2)\|([^|]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yA8cG1/1)

The `[^|]*` pattern will match zero or more characters other than `|`. Thus, there is even no need using a `\|` at the end.

Note that you can shrink the `(updatePanel1|updatePanel2)` part as `(updatePanel[12])`, or even `(updatePanel\d+)`.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly fine! Need to wait 10 minutes before I can accept the answer though.